# Can not find unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, syntax

People can see my site fine, but Google gets a 500 error.  I turned on all error reporting and I get this: unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';' on line 6.

I've gone over it many times, can't find anything wrong.  Hope someone can help.
If I take the line 5 which is  $(\'#js_terms_of_use\').click(function() and remove both \' the error on line 6 goes away, but I escaped them so I don't understand what the issue is.  Here's the code:

```
echo '
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$Behavior.termsAndPrivacy = function()
{
    $(\'#js_terms_of_use\').click(function()
    {
        '; ?>

        tb_show('<?php echo extras::getPhrase('user.terms_of_use', array('extras_squote' => true)); ?>', $.ajaxBox('page.view', 'height=410&width=600&title=terms')); 
        <?php echo '
        return false;
    });

    $(\'#js_privacy_policy\').click(function()
    {
        '; ?>

        tb_show('<?php echo extras::getPhrase('user.privacy_policy', array('extras_squote' => true)); ?>', $.ajaxBox('page.view', 'height=410&width=600&title=policy')); 
        <?php echo '
        return false;
    });
}
</script>
';
```

Comment: Why are you are trying to escape `"` in a single quoted string.

Comment: i don't, i just tried that for the heck of it.  forgot to remove that.

Comment: what's `tb_show()`  is that a js or php function?

Answer (score 3):

Anything outside of `<?php ?>` tags is echoed by default.  use this to your advantage.  Multi-line single-quoted strings are a bad idea.  Here's an attempt at cleaning your code up:

```
<?php 
$TOU  = extras::getPhrase('user.terms_of_use', array('extras_squote' => true));
$priv = extras::getPhrase('user.privacy_policy', array('extras_squote' => true));
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$Behavior.termsAndPrivacy = function()
{
    $('#js_terms_of_use').click(function()
    {
        tb_show('<?php echo $TOU ?>', $.ajaxBox('page.view', 'height=410&width=600&title=terms')); 
        return false;
    });

    $('#js_privacy_policy').click(function()
    {
        tb_show('<?php echo $priv ?>', $.ajaxBox('page.view', 'height=410&width=600&title=policy')); 
        return false;
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, didn't work either: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' on line 6

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to output multiple lines from a single echo in PHP use heredoc syntax (use newdoc syntax if available). For a refresher check them at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)

Comment: heredoc is definitely a step up from single quotes.  And definitely the solution of choice if you want to build a string rather than echoing output.

Comment: heredoc stopped the error, but it also stopped the ajax links from working, so I'll have to find another way.  Thank you so much for all the suggestions, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @WebMedia perhaps you are scaping the strings wrong? If the PHP error is gone, then the only explanation is that the output isn't corrent. So check the output (I mean see the source code in the browser) to see what is wrong.